# How to run the Scala code in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I am new to Scala, I write the simple code in scala, and tried to run it, but when I clicked "run as", it can not run, May I know the problem?

```
class Object {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val myVar: Int=0
    val myString: String="a"
    var myVar1 = 20
    val myVal1 = "Hello Scala new without datatype declaration."
    println(myVar1)
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Make sure you have Scala plugin installed in your Eclipse or possibly you can  download and use Scala IDE.

2.If your project is Maven,then right click your project, *configure->Add Scala Nature.*

3.**Your code shows you are having your main method in Scala class file but main methods are meant to be used in Scala Object file**. In Scala we have separate file type called object files.

```
object MyObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val myVar: Int=0
    val myString: String="a"
    var myVar1 = 20
    val myVal1 = "Hello Scala new without datatype declaration."
    println(myVar1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. In Scala, objects are singletons and classes are prototypes. In Java, we have our main methods as static which means, only once the object will be created. here almost same but Scala doesn't have any thing called Static. You can learn more on Scala tutorials on this regard.

Answer (score 0):

These links might be helpful:
* Eclipse Scala IDE http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/gettingstarted/index.html
* Scala Worksheet https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started

I recommend to start from worksheet if you want to practice short lines of code.